# Pick a value using a regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string in the format:

```
PROVIDER=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;User ID=sa;Server Name=UKServer;Server Port Address=5001;Initial Catalog=master
```

Using a regular expression in C# now can I get the value of Server Name?

Please note that Server Name could be in any location in the string and there may or may not be a space either side of the "=" i.e. the fomate could be

```
... Server Name=UKServer;....
... Server Name = UKServer;....
... Server Name =UKServer;....
... Server Name= UKServer;....
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really have to the parse the connection-string yourself; the handy [`OdbcConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)class can do it for you. It implements`IDictionary`, allowing you retrieve all of the attributes of the connection-string by key. I'm sure it is reasonably resistant to the different kinds of input that you mention, e.g. additional white-space, different ordering of key-vale pairs, etc.

Here's an example, tested for your sample:

```
var connString = @"PROVIDER=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;User ID=sa;Server Name=UKServer;Server Port Address=5001;Initial Catalog=master";

var connStringBuilder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder(connString);
var serverName = connStringBuilder["Server Name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_serverName = RegEx.Match(inputString, "Server Name ?= ?([\\w]+);").Groups(1).Value;
```

Breakdown:

```
Server Name ?= ?  // Normal string, the ? means that the preceding character
                  // or group is optional (0 or 1)
([\w]+);          // The parentheses define a group (the Group(0) is the
                  // always the whole match), so that you can easily get a
                  // substring of the match.
[\w]+             // Matches any alphabetical character, number or underscore
```

Comment: `[A-z]` is equivalent to `[A-Z\\[\\\\]^_\`a-z]`; I don't think that's really what you meant.

Comment: @Alan Moore: You're right...I always forget that `A-z` does also include other printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
"Server Name\s*=\s*(\w+)\s*;"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :

```
[^&]*(i?)(Server Name\s|)((i?)[a-z]);

_serverName = RegEx.Match(inputString, "[^&]*(i?)(Server Name\s|)((i?)[a-z]);").Groups(2).Value;
```